# GitHub, but without an account for issue submission (Or a similarly simple bug tracker, I suppose)

Tags: issue-tracker, help-desk, support-tracker

I'm part of a constantly changing organization that changes members every 4 years and I'd like to implement a system for users to submit problems with the organization without having to make an account. Also, I'd like it to be either free or ridiculously cheap.

The best solutions I've found so far involved me setting things up and hosting them from my computer, which can't work because I won't be the Vice President in 4 years, or involved at all in any way, so it's a short term solution. I need something that can be passed on simply by giving a password, not by passing down a server with the torch.

Essentially, I need something that does everything GitHub can do, but I need it to let people submit issues without needing to sign up. If that's not possible, I'll just use GitHub.

So, nearly essential features from most to least important are:

- Ticket submission without needing to make an account
- Ticket status includes merging, or at least duplicate tags
- Free
- Public access (lets everyone see submitted issues)
- Doesn't require someone in the organization to host it on their own server, just needs a password

Bonus features:

- Ability to contribute to bug discussions without an account
- Ticket prioritization

If you can't think of anything that gets all of these, the most super duper essential things are the free and not requiring someone hosting requirements. So, just the best thing you can think of.

Comment: Have a look into FogBugz from FogCreek. It's easy, it's free for 2 users, it's hosted. Not sure about the other requirements though.

Comment: On their pricing, I don't see an up to 2 option. I can try it for free for 30 days or it's up to 5 for 18 a month, billed annually.

Comment: @Marcel, fogbugz not dead?

Comment: @Pacerier yeah, by now, apparently. It was a good product at the time though. Thanks for pointing this out. Since the link now is kidnapped, I delete my previous comment.